# How many games did the Psycho Mantis know?

Tags: metal-gear-solid

In Metal Gear Solid, there was an [infamous scene](https://youtu.be/t0oHnGM_iQw?t=1m21s) with the Psycho Mantis, where he would read your mind and tell you other games that you have played (and make your controller vibrate).  Now I know that he would read the data off your memory card in your Playstation to determine this, but how many games did he know how to pronounce?

What would happen if there was absolutely nothing on the memory card?

Comment: In fact, he read the data saved on your memory card.
So he can know every games you played at while saving on that card :)

Comment: @Ise I know that he read the data, but is there a finite amount of games that he could pronounce?  I mean, the voice acting could only have done so much right?

Comment: Are you only asking about the PS1 version, or does *The Twin Snakes* count too?

Comment: @Nolonar I suppose both versions.  The Gamecube had memory cards also.

Comment: The wiki page say which games he can talk about : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycho_Mantis

Comment: @Ise thats in French.  Why not translate and post as answer?  What if nothing is on the memory card?  Does it say that too?

Comment: Ah ... Sorry. Totally forgot that I was on the french page ... So he can comment on the following Konami's games if you have at least one save :  Castlevania Chronicles, Suikoden, Vandal Hearts, Azure Dreams. He can add some things depending on your time in those games. 
In the Twin snakes version he can also speak about : The Legend of Zelda : The Wind Waker, Eternal Darkness, Super Smash Bros Melee  and Super Mario Sunshine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He can comment on the following Konami's games if you have at least one save:

- Castlevania Chronicles
- Suikoden
- Vandal Hearts
- Azure Dreams

He can add some things depending on your time in those games. In the Twin snakes version he can also speak about:

- The Legend of Zelda: The Wind Waker
- Eternal Darkness
- Super Smash Bros Melee
- Super Mario Sunshine

If nothing is on the memory card, he'll say that "your memory is completely clean"

[(Source)](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_wall)

Comment: Castlevania: Symphony of the Night is also recognized.